# Anything I can do to stop others using my productname as keyword in Google Adwords

Tags: google-ads

Is there anything I can do to stop others using my product name as keyword in adwords

Whenever I search for my product name it shows an advert for a competitor product. Im only a one-man micro business and haven't actually trademarked my product name but from the post below it sounds like even if I did it would not make any difference because trademarks are only considered in the advert text itself not in keywords

[AdWords: unauthorised use of trademark in keywords](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55546/adwords-unauthorised-use-of-trademark-in-keywords)

I took the advice of creating a new campaign with my product name as the keyword and directing user to my site but its says that I need a bid of £1.75 to show my advert, I cannot afford that, is there something I can do to reduce that cost.

Its worth noting that my product name is essentially an invented word which doesnt really clash with anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Google AdWords will block you if you try to use someone's trademark. And you can do exactly the same.

1. Trademark your product. There are many companies who perform this service professionally. Don't attempt to do it by yourself.
2. Fill the [Trademark Complain Form](https://services.google.com/inquiry/aw_tmcomplaint) on Google.
3. You will be the only one who can advertise your own trademark. Enjoy the prices as no one else will be outbidding you.

On the side, please note that you can bid on ads without meeting Google prices. Certainly your ads will not appear first or above the competition if you don't trademark your products, but this will save you considerable money while advertising, albeit not as good as bidding with a better sum. We have several keywords with ridiculous low biddings, and they still show and get clicked now and then.

Comment: I read that trademarks had no effect on keywords only the words in the displayed advert

Answer (score 1):

*Bidding wars.... working as intended*

There is nothing you can do, Google's aim is to make as much buck as possible and their bidding system is designed to drive up the price of adverts. Therefor their current design model is working as intended and there's not much you can do on broad keyword searches.

*Using Google Adwords is all about your profit margins*

A lot of people when deciding wither or not to use Google adwords for the first time make the mistake of being blinded by the bidding cost. Advertising is expensive and varies from  niche to niche, depending on the margin of profit on goods will ultimately effect the bidding price. A product with a margin profit of £10 vs a product margin of £100 will generally have a lower bidding price because you should expect your adword compagns  to eat into your profit margins. A high profit margin means you can normally afford bigger bidding prices.

*Conversion and profit margins*

When using Adwords you need to work out your conversion rate, so if your profit margin is £11.75 and it costs you £1.75 per a click and it takes you 5 clicks to get one sale meaning you spent £8.75, and your profit margin drops from £11.75 to £3.00, while this look awful its important to note that adwords is more beneficial for a bigger scale, 10 conversions that becomes £30.00 profit, on 100 customers £300 profit and on 1000, £3000.

*Keyword research*

A work around could be that you go for less competitive, and less broad keywords. A similar product that isn't very well know may cost much less meaning your profit margins in price. There are many Google Adword management companies that can assist you in keyword research and working out your conversion, of course this will eat into your margins again but, depending on volume of sales both these can still be ROI.

Comment: But my keyword is just my product name (songkong), it isn't well known and hence should not be expensive. The main reason I wanted to create this campaign was just to stop potential customers searching for my product inadvertently clicking link to a different product (tunesweeper)